How to make model know that LOW price always lesser or equal than CLOSE price?

I have this timeseries data, it retrieved based on last 1 day with 15m per timestep:



I perform global min-max scaling for entire series hence the range would be from 0 to 1:


3.In order to get better window_size, I analyze autocorrelation with lag latest 450 minutes, returning 11th node, which means there is correlation for 165 minutes lag:


Then performing rolling window based on that ACF which is 11 timestep:



For every window, I prefer future_size=1 which leads last node will be y target, while the others will be model input. The target is actually two features, which is LOW and CLOSE price at that timestep. I also performed local min-max scaling for every window:


6.Then I added some biases at CLOSE price that a bit lesser than actual data, while the LOW price adding epsilon that leads a bit higher than actual LOW price. The biases data will be used for feed to the neural network, while actual data will be used as validation:


I define invalid_price_metric, invalid price is defined as when the predicted LOW price is greater than CLOSE price which is impossible in real-world:

def invalid_price_metric(y_true, y_pred):
  true_low, true_close = y_true[:, 0], y_true[:, 1]
  pred_low, pred_close = y_pred[:, 0], y_pred[:, 1]
  len_data = true_low.shape[0]
  is_valid_price = pred_low <= pred_close
  num_of_invalid = len_data - ops.sum(is_valid_price)
  return num_of_invalid/len_data


But what I got, unexpected result where it returned invalid price.


Here is model.evaluate() returned from keras:
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 85ms/step - invalid_price_metric: 0.4828 - loss: 0.0286 - trade_loss_metric: 0.0920 - trade_profit_metric: 0.1149 - trade_ratio_metric: 0.5556


I trained with this simple LSTM architecture, where I feed the model with biased version input that has 5 features (Open, High, Low, Close, Volume) that returning future version of 2 features which is just Low and Close:

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(window_size-1, X_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dense(y_data.shape[-1], activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=[
  trade_profit_metric,
  trade_loss_metric,
  invalid_price_metric,
  trade_ratio_metric
])

model.summary()

I suspect I need special loss function to this in order to make model know that there is no single timestep where LOW price is greater than CLOSE price. The common regression loss like MSE, seems doesn't perform well.
I have verified it:
np.all(y_data[:, 0,0] <= y_data[:, 0,1], axis=-1) # (num of window, num of future, num of price type)

Returning: True

